# JXMapKit offline

Tags: java, maps

I use this code

```
final JXMapKit jXMapKit1 = new JXMapKit();
        jXMapKit1.setDefaultProvider(DefaultProviders.OpenStreetMaps);
        jXMapKit1.setCenterPosition(new GeoPosition(45.41984, -3.33924));
        jXMapKit1.setZoom(3);

        final List<GeoPosition> region = new ArrayList<GeoPosition>();
        region.add(new GeoPosition(5.42031, 100.34389));
        region.add(new GeoPosition(5.41984, 100.33924));
        region.add(new GeoPosition(5.42300, 100.33456));
        TileFactoryInfo info = new TileFactoryInfo(
        0, //min level
        8, //max allowed level
        10, // max level
        256, //tile size
        true, true, // x/y orientation is normal
        "file://D:/Tiles", // base url
        "x","y","z" // url args for x, y &amp; z
        ) {
    public String getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        return this.baseURL +"/"+zoom+"/"+x+"/"+y+".png";
    }
};
        jXMapKit1.setTileFactory(new DefaultTileFactory(info));
```

My tiles are create with maperitive.
But when i run my appli i have this error

> juin 06, 2013 8:10:05 AM
>   org.jdesktop.swingx.mapviewer.DefaultTileFactory$TileRunner run
>   SEVERE: Failed to load a tile at url: file://D:/Tiles/1/255/256.png,
>   retrying java.net.UnknownHostException: D

I don't understand why i have "D:/Tiles/1/**255/256**.png"

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
return this.baseURL +"/"+(10-zoom)+"/"+x+"/"+y+".png";
```

where the number 10 is your max level

source: https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/11/13/mapping-mashups-with-jxmapviewer.html#using-a-custom-map-server